# Including spotcolors in a DVI file

Tags: color, printing, dvi, dvips, ps

Consider, the PDF is generated using `DVI`-`PS`-`PDF`. Is there an easy way to add spotcolor in a `dvi` file, so that the resulting PDF contains the spotcolor.

I know that using `pdflatex` this is possible. Is this possible using `dvips` driver too?

Comment: Does anyone know solution for this question?

Comment: Is it an option to use `XeLaTeX` instead ?

Comment: Nope! I am using a traditional way dvi-ps-pdf.

Answer (score 4):

Been many years since I did spot colours in TeX/PostScript but here's what I remember. The PostScript Language Reference Manual (3rd edition) discusses color spaces and one simple example is given on page 245 under "Separation Color Spaces". This simple example creates some text in spot color called `LogoGreen` (from the PLRM) followed by some text in 100% K.

```
[ /Separation
(LogoGreen)
/DeviceCMYK
{ dup 0.84 mul
exch 0.0 exch dup 0.44 mul
exch 0.21 mul
}
] setcolorspace

/Times-Roman findfont 100 scalefont setfont
50 50 moveto (Hello) show
0 0 0 1 setcmykcolor 
/Times-Roman findfont 200 scalefont setfont
200 200 moveto (Hello) show
showpage
```

Download the PLRM as a PDF and check the details for yourself.I checked the resulting PDF (made with `Distiller`) and the `LogoGreen` does show up as a spot plate/colour in Acrobat Professional's output preview.  I guess you just need to write some PostScript using appropriate `\special{...}` commands --- and test thoroughly with your printers!!! Hope it's correct, and helps.