# How to use spotcolor inside \special for dvi -> ps -> pdf?

Tags: color, dvi, dvips

I have a bunch of old figures using the `picture` environment. To compile the figures I have to use the `dvi->dvips->ps2pdf` toolchain.

I need to change the colours in these pictures from `rgb` model to `cmyk` and a pantone colour. Using the answer in [this question,](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125543/2483) I manage to define the spot colour. My problem is that if I use it directly in the `\special` macro, the pdf viewer (evince) shows it black.

How should I tell dvips to use the defined spot colour?

### MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}{spot_color.pro}
TeXDict begin
/RedSpotCMYK [0 1 0 0] def
/RedSpotSpot (RedSpot) def
/RedSpotDef RedSpotCMYK aload pop RedSpotSpot findcmykcustomcolor def
/XC@RedSpot{RedSpotDef 1.0 setcustomcolor}XCdef
end
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[prologue]{xcolor}

\usepackage[tightpage,active,psfixbb]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}
\PreviewEnvironment{picture}

\definecolor{RedSpot}{cmyk}{0 1 0 0}

\usepackage{eepic}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.254mm}
\begin{picture}(340,225)(100,-420)
  % This compiles but arrow shows black
  \special{RedSpot 1}\allinethickness{0.508mm}\path(110,-395)(170,-300)\special{sh 1}\path(170,-300)(167,-302)(168,-303)(169,-304)(170,-300) % Plain Solid Arrow
  % This has compilation error:
  % ps2pdf spotcolor-picture.ps
  % Error: /undefined in TeXcolorRedSpot
  % \special{color RedSpot 1}\allinethickness{0.508mm}\path(110,-395)(170,-300)\special{sh 1}\path(170,-300)(167,-302)(168,-303)(169,-304)(170,-300) % Plain Solid Arrow
  % With the CMYK model it shows correctly
  %  \special{color cmyk 0 1 0 0}\allinethickness{0.508mm}\path(110,-395)(170,-300)\special{sh 1}\path(170,-300)(167,-302)(168,-303)(169,-304)(170,-300) % Plain Solid Arrow
   \special{color cmyk 1 0 0 0}\allinethickness{0.508mm}\path(110,-395)(380,-310)\special{color cmyk 1 0 0 0}\path(380,-310)(377,-310)(377,-311)(377,-312)(380,-310) % Plain Solid Arrow
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

I use the following commands to compile

```
latex spotcolor-picture.tex
dvips -h tex.pro -h xcolor.pro -h spot_color.pro spotcolor-picture.dvi
ps2pdf spotcolor-picture.ps
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of your color is `XC@RedSpot`, and you can't use arbitrary words inside a special, they are normally keywords. If you want to insert postscript literally you can use the `ps: keyword`.

The following seems to work (I removed the preview and the other colors, they complicated the tests).

```
\begin{filecontents*}{spot_color.pro}
TeXDict begin
/RedSpotCMYK [0 1 0 0] def
/RedSpotSpot (RedSpot) def
/RedSpotDef RedSpotCMYK aload pop RedSpotSpot findcmykcustomcolor def
/XC@RedSpot{RedSpotDef 1.0 setcustomcolor}XCdef
end
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eepic}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
abc 
\begin{picture}(10,10)
\special{ps:  XC@RedSpot 1 setcolor} 
\put(0,0){\line(1,1){10}}
\put(0,10){\line(1,-1){10}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This seems to work too (but you then can't add a tint to the color:

```
\begin{picture}(10,10)
\special{color push  XC@RedSpot} 
\put(0,0){\line(1,1){10}}
\put(0,10){\line(1,-1){10}}
\special{color pop   XC@RedSpot}
\end{picture}
```

Comment: I'd change `XCdef` to `bind def` (or even could be `def`), then you can add `\AtBeginDvi{\special{header=spot_color.pro}}` and not have to worry about headers (or of course you could add the stuff directly as a special)

Comment: I thought that `XC@`  was done kind of naming convention. Can I remove this part?

Comment: We discussed that a bit and shortened the code, the current state is here https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55364585#55364585

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks for linking the interesting discussion :-) Always trying to learn.